# ErrorException (E_ERROR) Undefined variable: age (View: /home/....profile.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am getting an error on a recycled code which works perfectly fine in another section of the app..

Controller :

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    $gender = Gender::pluck('name', 'id')->all();
    $age = Age::pluck('group', 'id')->all();
    return view('profile', compact('user', 'gender', 'age'));
}
```

View :

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('age_id', 'Age Group: ') !!}
    {!! Form::select('age_id', $age, null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

Request :

```
public function authorize()
{
    return Auth::check();
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        // 'name'      =>  'required|string|min:4|max:40',
        // 'email'     =>  'required|string|email|min:8|max:40|unique:users',
        // 'photo_id'  =>  'required',
        // 'gender_id' =>  'required',
        // 'age_id'    =>  'required',
        // 'password'  =>  'required|string|min:8|max:16'
    ];
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "compact()" function, you are passing 3 variables as a string:

```
       return view('profile', compact('user', 'gender', 'age'));
```

You have to pass them inside an array:

```
       return view('profile', compact(['user', 'gender', 'age']));
```

I will have to see the Model if this doesn't fix the bug, but for now is the only thing that I can see.
Let us know the results.